# Как реализовать динамический массив в C?

Tags: c, массивы

Есть программа на C, которая считывает данные (числа) с клавиатуры таким образом:

```
while (scanf ("%d", &number) != EOF) {
    ...
}
```

Необходимо заполнить массив A этими числами. Количество вводимых чисел неизвестно. Как лучше это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Классически - воспользоватся realloc. Вот [здесь](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/realloc/) даже вполне подходящий пример.

Comment: Ага, спасибо. То, что искал.